# Swapping old capacitors for modern caps

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor, replacement

I am trying to repair/refurbish an old Farnell L30d power supply, 0 - 30v and current limiting to 2 amps.
There are two caps inside, one of which has blown. The caps are Hunts 3132A. Hunts no longer exist.
I have a circuit diagram for the ps and it shows these caps are 2200nf 63v high ripple.

Can I just replace the caps, with any old modern 2200nf 63v electrolytic caps? The ones I have found on eBay are considerably small tha  the ones fitted, so is it just a case of securely mounting the new ones? They are connected in parallel.

Comment: Do you really mean 2200nF == 2.2µF? If yes, I wouldn't bother with electrolytic caps at all but use PP ones.

Comment: A picture speaks a thousand words.

Comment: And if you actually meant 2200uF 63V, then get any good quality modern equivalent.  Just avoid dubious suppliers or the new capacitors won't last long.

Comment: Does the circuit diagram that you have happen to have a note near the bottom left stating "ALL CAPACITOR VALUES IN μF" like the one linked to on [Farnell L30 Stabilised Voltage Supply 1963 Germanium](http://ukradio.info/Farnell_L30/)?

Comment: Andrew, thank you. Yes, I did mean 2200uf and 63 volts. The link does show the ps, but it is later than that, not germanium, it is the section later, which h starts "from about 1969" all silicon, I believe. I think that is also where I got the manual and diagram from.

Comment: I cannot find anything of the same physical size, will that matter

Comment: @RobManser It only matters if the capacitor is mounted to a PCB and needs to fit in a certain amount of space. You have not posted any photos though, so it's difficult to picture the setup

Comment: Is the capacitor vertical or horizontal?

Comment: Thank you all for your kind responses, I have now changed the caps, with your help and all seems to be working fine now - time will tell I guess. Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the actual value of the capacitors is 2200**u**F, any modern electrolytic of the same physical size and value from a reputable company should work. Make sure it's rated for *at least* 63V, more is ok. Slightly higher capacitance may be ok, but we would need to see the circuit diagram to confirm this. Try to find caps from Panasonic, EPCOS, Nichicon, Rubycon, or Nippon-Chemicon. They are some of the most reputable capacitor manufacturers out there.

Comment: It is certainly 2200uf my mistake. As above, I think that is where the circuit diagram is. I have looked around for suitable caps already, but there is nothing remotely near the same physical size. These are about 75mm long, by about 40mm dia. I guess that's how much things have changed. Should I mount them on some heats ink?

Comment: As long as you can get a capacitor with a similar pin spacing and narrower body (less than 40mm), it should work. What is the lead spacing of the original capacitor? Can you post a photo? You should not need a heat sink for a capacitor.

Comment: And even if you can't get the same pin spacing, just by leaded capacitors - radial or axial - and bend the leads to fit.  No need for heatsinks.